# Convert string in to number?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like "3.9" I want to convert this string in to a number without using split function.

If string is   3.9 => o/p 39

If string is 1.2.3 => o/p 123

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose is. Would it work for your case to just remove the periods and parse the number?

```
int result = Int32.Parse(str.Replace(".", String.Empty));
```

Comment: It appears the op wants to be able to store floating points so wouldn't a double be more suitable?

Comment: @m.edmondson: In both the examples the output is an integer value.

Comment: Really, why is this?  Do you have any links to point me to some information?

Comment: @m. edmondson: What are you talking about? Look at the examples in the question.

Comment: Sorry I see what you mean, I was under the impression he wanted to store 3.9 as a datatype not 39.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) the `.` with empty string before trying to parse it:

```
string inputString = "1.2.3";
int number = int.Parse(inputString.Replace(".", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "3.9";
str = str.Replace(".","");

int i;
int.TryParse(str, out i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with something like this:

```
string str = "3.2";
str = str.Replace(".", "");

double number = convert.ToDouble(str);
```

Comment: Try it now - I was missing a bit out

Comment: @m.edmoundson Why double? He's after ints

Comment: @razlebe - Because 3.2 can't be represented as an int, in the question all he said was _string in to a number_.  Double _is_ a number.

Comment: @m.edmondson He clearly specifies that he's looking to strip out the decimal points too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Replace(".",""); for this purpose

eg:

```
string stnumber= "5.9.2.5";
int number =  Convert.ToInt32(stnumber.Replace(".", ""));
```

i think `Convert.ToInt32();` is better than `int.Parse();`

Comment: Whether `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int32.Parse` is better depends on the expected behaviour. `Convert.ToIn32` will for example convert an empty string into zero, which may not always be desirable.